# What is Hybrid Driven and Keyword Driven in selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Please give an example for Hybrid Driven and Keyword Driven using selenium. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe by Hybrid Driven testing you meant hybrid testing. It is a combination of Keyword driven testing and Data driven testing and other frameworks !!

Comment: Yes, you're right. Can I have examples for both Hybrid Driven and Keyword driven?

Answer (score 0):

Never heard about Hybrid driven testing, you might be referring to testing [**hybrid applications**](http://searchsoftwarequality.techtarget.com/definition/hybrid-application-hybrid-app).

> A hybrid application (hybrid app) is one that combines elements of
>   both native and Web applications. Native applications are developed
>   for a specific platform and installed on a computing device. Web
>   applications are generalized for multiple platforms and not installed
>   locally but made available over the Internet through a browser. Hybrid
>   apps are often mentioned in the context of mobile computing.

About [**Keyword driven testing**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyword-driven_testing), each keyword corresponds to an individual testing action like a mouse click, selection of a menu item, keystrokes, opening or closing a window or other actions. A keyword-driven test is a sequence of operations, in a keyword format, that simulate user actions on the tested application.

Answer (score 0):

Posted below is a simple class for Hybrid (Modular and Data Driven) framework -

SearchData.java

Has the code for data to be used in the test.

```
package com.data;

public class SearchData {
    private String url;
    private String searchWord;

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getSearchWord() {
        return searchWord;
    }

    public void setSearchWord(String searchWord) {
        this.searchWord = searchWord;
    }
}
```

SearchPage.java

Contains modules of code.

```
package com.page;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import com.data.SearchData;

public class SearchPage {
    WebDriver driver;

    public SearchPage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void launchGoogle(SearchData searchData) {
        driver.get(searchData.getUrl());
    }

    public void search(SearchData searchData) {
        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys(searchData.getSearchWord());
        driver.findElement(By.name("btnG")).click();
    }

}
```

GoogleTest.java

Contains the actual Junit Test.

```
package com.test;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import com.data.SearchData;
import com.page.SearchPage;

public class GoogleTest {
    protected WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
    }

    @Test
    public void searchTest() throws InterruptedException {
        // set the data
        SearchData searchData = new SearchData();
        searchData.setUrl("https://www.google.com");
        searchData.setSearchWord("Selenium");

        // call the methods
        SearchPage searchPage = new SearchPage(driver);
        searchPage.launchGoogle(searchData);
        searchPage.search(searchData);
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }
}
```

The above code is pretty basic and can be enhanced to a great extend.

As for Keyword driven framework use SELENIUM IDE / ROBOT FRAMEWORK.